# Pdf Upload in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, zend-framework2

I'm just trying to upload a pdf file in my Project (coded with Zend Framework 2). I just can't figure out why nothing is uploaded.

The Controller:

```
$this->adapter = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('db-adapter');
    $jobModel = new Model\JobModel($this->adapter);
    $form    = EnterContentForm::getEnterContentFormJob($this->serviceManager);
    $templateData = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('TemplateData');
    $templateData->addTemplateData(array(
            'ckEditor' => true
    ));


    if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
                    $pdfFile = $this->params()->fromFiles('pdf');

        $data    = array_merge_recursive(
                $this->getRequest()->getPost()->toArray(),
                $this->getRequest()->getFiles()->toArray()
        );
        $isPdf = new \Zend\Validator\File\MimeType('application/pdf');
        $form->setData($postData);


        if($form->isValid()){
            if($isPdf->isValid($pdfFile)){
                $adapter = new \Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http(); 
                $adapter->setDestination("static_content\media\pdfs\jobs");
                $adapter->receive($pdfFile['name']);
            }}
```

I can't figure out why nothing is uploaded.
I tried many ways but none of them worked, like:

[Abdul Malik Ikhsan's Blog](http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/08/31/zend-framework-2-creating-upload-form-file-validation/)

[Zend Doku](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.form.file-upload.html)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For my projects I use [Christopher Martin](https://github.com/cgmartin) [ZF2FileUploadExamples](https://github.com/cgmartin/ZF2FileUploadExamples) and it work for me